# Toggling a checkbox in the operator panel

Tags: python

I'm coding a script with a toggleable checkbox that is supposed to work just as the Cut Through one in The Knife Project does. I created the checkbox with the `a=bpy.props.BoolPrperty()` and can't toggle it. Attempts with

```
if self.a == True: 
#code 
else: 
#code2 
return{'FINISHED'}
```

don't give the desired effect.
Is it possible with `wm.context_toggle()`?

Comment: Hello, Lukasz, if you would be so good as to tell us that @Gorgious is correctly on to your problem in his comment above, (or not) we can close this out. (Or not) :)

Comment: @Robin Betts: Yes, he is.

Comment: Also note `if self.a == True: ` usually can be reduced to `if self.a:`